# Glitch while scrolling listview in wp8.1 RT

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

In my ListView i have to show 150+ data and it has combination of text and images to display. So when i scroll listview a bit faster then it start to show black glitch. I find few technique to minimize it but doesn't work well. Setting CacheMode technique it works some how but not properly (still black glitch) and also reduce performance. I also see UI Virtualization method but not sure how to implement this. So how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` in WP8.1 RT uses virtualization by default with the `ItemsStackPanel` items panel, so if you haven't changed the `ItemsPanel` property explicitly this should not be a problem.

Maybe the problem are the size of the images you display. Try to use `BitmapImage` with `DecodePixelWidth/Height` properties set so the rendering is faster if the image size is too big.

Maybe your `ItemTemplate` is too complex and if so, try to minimize the number of elements in it.

For more info read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994641.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994637.aspx).